# Transparent object within transparent object in eevee does not display

Tags: shaders, transparency, eevee-render-engine

I have 3 objects in blender. They are inside one another(think russian nesting dolls) and each one is transparent except for the inner-most object. 
My problem is I cannot view all three objects through each other at the same time. I can either see the smallest object within the largest one or the second smallest object inside the largest one but never all three.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/133780/, https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/141406/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't see a glass object through another glass object in Eevee](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133780/cant-see-a-glass-object-through-another-glass-object-in-eevee)